# REshaping input data for LSTM

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, input, deep-learning

I have 1000 configurations. Each of which has 1000 points and in each point, the information for 6 (up to 9) features have been observed. I want to take the last column as my target and the rest of the table would be my input training dataset. Now in order to feed up the LSTM network, I faced an initial problem of creating the input data set. I do not know how to reshape the 3D matrix. The primary code which I wrote is below:

```
# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))
```

I'm sure this code is not suitable for my problem but if you could give me a favor, I will be thankful.

Comment: LSTMs are meant for sequence data, is your data a sequence or a time series?

Comment: why you want to use `LSTM` and what type of data you have

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have a sequence of data that are repeating. For instance, each year I have data for the same points.

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat Because I have a `sequential` process that is repeating. Maybe, you ask why `LSTM` and why not RNN. I decided to use `LSTM` since I understood this one is more compatible with my problems than `RNN` but I'm not sure(Based on searching)

Comment: Are you using this time information with the LSTM?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, yes. I am providing staff for LSTM since I guess still it's feasible.

Comment: You should use the year information to assemble a sequence of data, which should go into the timesteps dimension (the second dimension)

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I wrote this but I am not sure whether it is correct or not. `y = df.iloc[:,5]
X1 = df.iloc[:,0]
X2 = df.iloc[:,1]
X3 = df.iloc[:,2]
X4 = df.iloc[:,3]
X5 = df.iloc[:,4]
X = np.column_stack((X1,X2,X3,X4,X5))
x = np.reshape(1000,1,5)` but for spliting between train and test I got another error.